# SurveyMonkey API get_survey_details

Tags: api, surveymonkey

Why is get_survey_details response returning this error msg?

When running a request via the SurveyMonkey API for the get_survey_details method

https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_details

The response is:

{"status":3,"errmsg":"Survey requested 'xxxxxxx' has more than 200 pages" }

This is a custom app, using the API key and token generated in the API console.  My user has the Gold plan.

The online guide for the api indicates a limit (any plan level) of 1000 questions and 1000 pages.  https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/limits

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The max page size limit is used for pagination. It represents the maximum number of resource items that can be returned for a page. For example, you can only fetch a maximum of 1000 surveys from `/v2/surveys/get_survey_list` per call.

I've updated the docs to provide a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the number of pages a survey can have in order to be serviceable by SurveyMonkey's API. 200 is the hard limit currently configured.

That limit is documented [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/limits) as, "1000 questions or 200 pages, surveys over limit will not be returned"